# unable to align tables side by side in latex

Tags: tables, minipage

I am trying to align tables side by side in latex but i was unable to do using `minipage`. I have mentioned the latex code below to make the table side by side

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}

I32             & optimizer & Loss & PSNR  \\
\hline
      & Adam     & Mean Square Error   & 0    \\
     & Adam     & DSSIM               & 0    \\
     & Adam     & PSNR loss           & 1    \\
     & Adam     & Mean Absolute Error & 1    \\
     & Ranger   & Mean Absolute Error + Mean Gradient Error & \\
     & Ranger   & Mean Absolute Error + Mean Gradient Error + KL Loss &\\
     & Ranger   & Mean Absolute Error + KL Loss & \\
     & Ranger   & Mean Absolute Error + KL Loss + Mean Gradient Error &\\
     & Ranger21 & Mean Absolute Error & \\
     & Ranger21 & Mean Absolute Error + KL Loss & \\
     & Ranger21 & Mean Absolute Error + 0.75 KL Loss & \\
     & Ranger21 & Mean Absolute Error + 0.5 KL Loss & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
I43 & optimizer & Loss & PSNR  \\
\hline
    & Adam     & Mean Square Error   & 0    \\
     & Adam     & DSSIM               & 0    \\
     & Adam     & PSNR loss           & 1    \\
     & Adam     & Mean Absolute Error & 1    \\
     & Ranger   & Mean Absolute Error + Mean Gradient Error & \\
     & Ranger   & Mean Absolute Error + Mean Gradient Error + KL Loss &\\
     & Ranger   & Mean Absolute Error + KL Loss & \\
     & Ranger   & Mean Absolute Error + KL Loss + Mean Gradient Error &\\
     & Ranger21 & Mean Absolute Error & \\
     & Ranger21 & Mean Absolute Error + KL Loss & \\
     & Ranger21 & Mean Absolute Error + 0.75 KL Loss & \\
     & Ranger21 & Mean Absolute Error + 0.5 KL Loss & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  To get two minipages sidy by side on a page, remove the empty line between the them. Apart from that, your tables look quite wide and I would guess, thex don't fit side by side onto a portrait page. Do you get any overfull \box warnings if you compile your code?

Comment: In your tables, you declare a total of 8 columns, but the tables only really need/use 4 columns. Is this intentional?

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for commenting, I am very new to latex, I have took this code from a template and modifying it. where i have used 8 columns. I am using only 4 columns. Its not intentional.

Comment: Since both tables are quite wide and unlikely to fit side by side and on top of that share a lot of the same information, would you mind combining them into a single table? Also, what exactly is the difference between the two tables (apart from the number in the upper left cell)?

Comment: I have this type of same 16 tables so i want to arrange them as a grid. No, they are different, once i fill the PSNR values they look different. I am wrapping this table in `scalebox`

Comment: Wrapping a table in a `\scalebox` will result in inconsistenz font sizes throughout the document. You may want to avoid that.

Comment: I have updated the screen shot of the tables i am trying to make them look like a grid of tables

Comment: Do all 16 tables share the same entries in the "optimizer"  and "loss"  columns and only differ in the numbers in the "PSNR" column? If so, there is not really a reason for repeating this information 16 times. A combined table could for example look like this:: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7VTo.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127828/discussion-between-harsha-and-leandriis).

Comment: How wide and how tall is the text block? Alternatively, which page size do you employ and how wide are the margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest one of the following two alternative layouts, that use just 2 instead of 16 tables as well as abbreviations (similar to the ones used by Mico [in their answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606093/134144))

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{c}}
\toprule
               & \multicolumn{8}{c}{PSNR}\\
\cmidrule{2-9}
 Loss &  (I32) &  (I43) &  (I87) &  (I32) &  (I43) &  (I87) &  (I32) &  (I43)  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Adam}\\
 MSE   & 0   & 0 & 0 \\
 DSSIM               & 0   & 0 & 0  \\
 PSNR loss           & 1   & 1 & 1 \\
 MAE & 1   & 1 & 1 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger}\\
 MAE + MGE           & \\
 MAE + MGE + KLL &\\
 MAE + KLL & \\
 MAE + KLL + MGE &\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger21}\\
 MAE& \\
 MAE + KLL & \\
 MAE + 0.75 KLL & \\
 MAE + 0.5 KLL & \\
 \midrule
                & \multicolumn{8}{c}{PSNR}\\
\cmidrule{2-9}
 Loss &  (I32) &  (I43) &  (I87) &  (I32) &  (I43) &  (I87) &  (I32) &  (I43)  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Adam}\\
 MSE   & 0   & 0 & 0 \\
 DSSIM               & 0   & 0 & 0  \\
 PSNR loss           & 1   & 1 & 1 \\
 MAE & 1   & 1 & 1 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger}\\
 MAE + MGE           & \\
 MAE + MGE + KL Loss &\\
 MAE + KL Loss & \\
 MAE + KL Loss + MGE &\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger21}\\
 MAE& \\
 MAE + KLL & \\
 MAE + 0.75 KL Loss & \\
 MAE + 0.5 KL Loss & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\smallskip

\footnotesize
MSE: Mean Square Error; MAE: Mean Absolute Error; MGE: Mean Gradient Error

\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll*{8}{c}}
\toprule
               && \multicolumn{8}{c}{PSNR}\\
\cmidrule{3-10}
optimizer  & Loss &  (I32) &  (I43) &  (I87) &  (I32) &  (I43) &  (I87) &  (I32) &  (I43)  \\
\midrule
Adam & MSE       & 0   & 0 & 0 \\
     & DSSIM     & 0   & 0 & 0  \\
     & PSNR loss & 1   & 1 & 1 \\
     & MAE       & 1   & 1 & 1 \\
\addlinespace
Range &  MAE + MGE           & \\
      & MAE + MGE + KLL &\\
      & MAE + KLL & \\
      & MAE + KLL + MGE &\\
\addlinespace
Ranger21 & MAE& \\
         & MAE + KLL & \\
         & MAE + 0.75 KLL & \\
         & MAE + 0.5 KLL & \\
\midrule
               && \multicolumn{8}{c}{PSNR}\\
\cmidrule{3-10}
optimizer  & Loss &  (I32) &  (I43) &  (I87) &  (I32) &  (I43) &  (I87) &  (I32) &  (I43)  \\
\midrule
Adam & MSE       & 0   & 0 & 0 \\
     & DSSIM     & 0   & 0 & 0  \\
     & PSNR loss & 1   & 1 & 1 \\
     & MAE       & 1   & 1 & 1 \\
\addlinespace
Range &  MAE + MGE           & \\
      & MAE + MGE + KLL &\\
      & MAE + KLL & \\
      & MAE + KLL + MGE &\\
\addlinespace
Ranger21 & MAE& \\
         & MAE + KLL & \\
         & MAE + 0.75 KLL & \\
         & MAE + 0.5 KLL & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\smallskip

\footnotesize
MSE: Mean Square Error; MAE: Mean Absolute Error; MGE: Mean Gradient Error

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to drastically simplify and streamline the tables just to get two tables to fit side by side. The following code gives an example of how this may be done.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} llc @{} }
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{I32}}\\
Optimizer & Loss & PSNR \\
\hline
Adam     & MSE        & 0   \\
Adam     & DSSIM      & 0   \\
Adam     & PSNR loss  & 1   \\
Adam     & MAE        & 1   \\
Ranger   & MAE + MGE  &     \\
Ranger   & MAE + MGE + KLL &\\
Ranger   & MAE + KLL  &     \\
Ranger   & MAE + KLL + MGE &\\
Ranger21 & MAE        &     \\
Ranger21 & MAE + KLL  &     \\
Ranger21 & MAE + 0.75 KLL & \\
Ranger21 & MAE + 0.5 KLL &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hspace{\fill}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} llc @{} }
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{I43}}\\
Optimizer & Loss & PSNR \\
\hline
Adam     & MSE       & 0    \\
Adam     & DSSIM     & 0    \\
Adam     & PSNR loss & 1    \\
Adam     & MAE       & 1    \\
Ranger   & MAE + MGE &      \\
Ranger   & MAE + MGE + KLL &\\
Ranger   & MAE + KLL &      \\
Ranger   & MAE + KLL + MGE &\\
Ranger21 & MAE       &      \\
Ranger21 & MAE + KLL &      \\
Ranger21 & MAE + 0.75 KLL & \\
Ranger21 & MAE + 0.5 KLL &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\noindent
\dots
\end{document}
```